# Using input type="submit" to change content

Tags: javascript, html, submit

Okay, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very obvious here, but I just couldn't find a proper solution so far. What I'm trying to do is simple: Have a user write something into a form, have him submit the form, and write that input into a textarea on the same page.

This is my code:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<form name='registration'>
<label for="input">Input:</label>
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="execute()"/>
</form>

<div id="results">
<span>Result</span>
<span><textarea cols="30" rows="5" id="resulttext" readonly="readonly"></textarea> </span>
</div>

<script>
function execute()
{
    var result = document.getElementById("input").value

    document.getElementById("resulttext").value=result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now what happens if I enter something into the form is that the textarea briefly shows my input before reverting back to showing nothing. My guess is that the textarea field is only changed for the duration of the execute() function.

When I change `input type="submit"` to a `<button>` everything works as intended, but I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cancel the default event for the submit button, otherwise it just submits the form (which in this case essentially reloads the page since there are no form elements with names). Add `return false;`after `execute()` (put a `;` in between the two pieces)

Comment: He could also use a <button> instead of an <input>.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! Strange I haven't found any documentation anywhere that explicitly mentions this.

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma `<button>`s still submit forms in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Because your button is of type `submit`, it will submit your form after executing the `execute()` method. You can change the button type to `type="button"` and you will not have this submit behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/PCCbh/

Note - using `<button>` is okay in this case. It is essentially the same as `<input type="button"`.